# J++ COM object won't create on server 2003

Tags: vbscript, com, server, windows-server-2003, j++

I have a (very) old COM object created in J++ that currently runs on Server 2000. I'm migrating it to Server 2003 but when trying to create an object in VBScript or Classic ASP I get an 'Out Of Memory' error.

The J++ class does very little, other than create network sockets and send messages across the network. I don't believe the constructor does much at all, so can't see what could cause this error. This works perfectly on the Server 2000 instance.

I've installed MS Java 5.0.3810 on both servers and don't believe there are any other dependencies. I've also registered the COM object.

Does anyone have any ideas how I can diagnose this issue?

Comment: Is DEP disabled in `boot.ini` (via `/noexecute=AlwaysOff`) on your 2003 box?